# How can I efficiently compare two DateTimes and check if they are the same day?

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

I have two `DateTime` objects

```
$lastDate = $entity->getDate(); // is a DateTime with same format as $today
$today    = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d'));
```

Now I want to check, if those two dates are the same day, or if they are more than one day apart (but this shall also include if `$lastDay` is yesterday at 11pm and `$today` is 1 am the new day).

What I have so far is

```
$diff = $today->diff($lastDate);

if($diff->days > 0) {
    $return = false;
} else {
    $return = true;
}
```

The problem is: This seems to count if the dates are more than 24 hours away from each other and only sets to `true` if that is the case.

I could think of comparing them by comparing `$date->format('d');`, but this would imply that I check year and month as well. I know this would work flawlessly, but this would be a five-liner or so.

So my question is: Is there a more *efficient* way to check this? Any operation like `diff()` that gives me the result in a one-liner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on your latest change, wouldn't this work:

```
$votedToday = ($today->format('Y-m-d') == $lastDate->format('Y-m-d'));
```

I agree it's kind of strange that DateTime doesn't have a method to just extract the date portion, similar to MySQL, but if you're going to use `format`, why not skip the `diff` and just compare the formatted date string for the full date of both DateTime objects?

And to simplify it further, you could use:

```
$votedToday = ($lastDate->format('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d'));
```

Assuming you are only using `$today` to confirm if `$lastDate` is on today.

Comment: Nice approach, nice and lean thinking. Thanks!